# Odoo 10 - Print address labels for partners and contacts

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I would like to know if there is something "out of the box" in Odoo 10 community to print labels (shipping labels).
I see a "Label" field in res.partner view, but not sure if it is related or not.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation of Label tag with partner address and contact labels. Label tag is used to give string for particular field.

```
<label for="type" string="Type"/>
<div name="div_type">
   <field name="type" class="oe_inline"/>
</div>
```